# Jenkins when to use script in a step?

Tags: jenkins

I was looking at some old jenkins code.
All of our steps contain the script tag.
e.g.

```
stage("create_baseline"){
    steps {
        script {
            sh("""some commands """)
            created_patch = sh(returnStdout: true, script:  """some other command""")
            echo "created patch ${created_patch}"
        }
    }
}
```

When reading the [jenkins docs about script](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#script) it says:

> the script step should be unnecessary in Declarative Pipelines, but it
> can provide a useful "escape hatch". script blocks of non-trivial size
> and/or complexity should be moved into Shared Libraries instead.

Reading the description I tried to come up with, non library related, examples of  when to use the script tag but can not come up with any. Can someone explain when to use script tag inside of steps? Im curious if I can just remove all script tags, or if there are some cases when it is actually needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc also says:

> The script step takes a block of Scripted Pipeline and executes that in the Declarative Pipeline.

Basically, the script block allows you to use scripted pipeline syntax inside a declarative pipeline, which means you can write regular groovy code and use most of the abilities Groovy gives you once you open up a `script` block.

As for whether you can remove the script blocks depends on whether you have used regular Groovy code in your pipeline. For example, have you used the `def` keyword to define a variable? If so, then you can't remove the script block since that is part of a scripted pipeline.